# Creating a vector from a file in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and my question should be trivial. I need to create a word cloud from a txt file containing the words and their occurrence number. For that purposes I am using the [snippets package](http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/snippets/cloud.html).
As it can be seen at the bottom of the link, first I have to create a vector (is that right that words is a vector?) like bellow.

```
> words <- c(apple=10, pie=14, orange=5, fruit=4)
```

My problem is to do the same thing but create the vector from a file which would contain words and their occurrence number. I would be very happy if you could give me some hints.

Moreover, to understand the format of the file to be inserted I write the vector words to a file.

```
> write(words, file="words.txt")
```

However, the file words.txt contains only the values but not the names(apple, pie etc.).

```
$ cat words.txt
10 14 5 4
```

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the snippets package. I wasn't aware of that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`words` is a *named* vector, the distinction is important in the context of the `cloud()` function if I read the help correctly.

Write the data out correctly to a file:

```
write.table(words, file = "words.txt")
```

Create your word occurrence file like the txt file created. When you read it back in to R, you need to do a little manipulation:

```
> newWords <- read.table("words.txt", header = TRUE)
> newWords
        x
apple  10
pie    14
orange  5
fruit   4
> words <- newWords[,1]
> names(words) <- rownames(newWords)
> words
 apple    pie orange  fruit 
    10     14      5      4
```

What we are doing here is reading the file into `newWords`, the subsetting it to take the one and only column (variable), which we store in `words`. The last step is to take the row names from the file read in and apply them as the "names" on the `words` vector. We do the last step using the `names()` function.

Comment: For a one liner, use `as.matrix(read.table('words.txt'))[, 1]` (matrix subsetting propagates names whereas data.frame doesn't).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 'vector' is the proper term.

EDIT:
A better method than write.table would be to use save() and load():

```
save(words. file="svwrd.rda")
load(file="svwrd.rda")
```

The save/load combo preserved all the structure rather than doing coercion. The write.table followed by names()<- is kind of a hassle as you can see in both Gavin's answer here and my answer on rhelp.

Initial answer:
Suggest you use as.data.frame to coerce to a dataframe an then write.table() to write to a file.

```
write.table(as.data.frame(words), file="savew.txt")
saved <- read.table(file="savew.txt")
saved
       words
apple     10
pie       14
orange     5
fruit      4
```

Comment: but isn't the OP wanting to create an appropriate text file from the occurrence data and read *that* into R? The `write.table()` business was to see how the file *should* be formatted for subsequent import into R, whilst preserving the names.

Comment: I didn't think the OP was particularly clear. Only be reference to his cross-posting in r-help did it appear that he might have a text file already. This question appeared to ask how to preserve the attributes of a named vector that was already in the workspace.

Comment: Ah, OK. Haven't seen the R-Help posting yet, bit behind on that email folder.

Comment: And I stand behind my advice to use save and load if the goal is storing something that exists in the workspace for later use in R. If for some reason it needed to be "text" then I would advise the  dump() / source() pair of functions.